# How to create combo box with custom category headers

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to create a combo box with custom category headers in access. The values for the combo box are not taken from a table, but the selected value will be stored in a table.

I want the outcome of the combo box to look like this, for example:

**Fruits**

```
Apples

Bananas

Pears
```

**Meat**

```
Chicken

Beef
```

**Dairy**

```
Milk

Eggs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple combo boxes then you can. Just tell it that you have headers and the first entry will count as the header.

EDIT: after reading that you want a single combo box, I don't know of a way to do it like you want it.

Comment: "**a** combo box with custom category header**s**"

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using multiple boxes with the first box being the category and filtered the second box based on the selection of the first combo box

Answer (score 0):

You can have it look like this example:

```
Fruits
-Apples    
-Bananas    
-Pears
Meat
-Chicken    
-Beef
Dairy
-Milk    
-Eggs
```

That about it. Then filter for selections not starting with a dash.